# How to sort product collection in shopify?

Tags: sorting, collections, shopify, product, liquid

I have a problem with my shopify collection. in the theme only i have sort by date , name etc but i am looking for sorting through colour.

For example: I have a collection of product in Red, Blue, Pink, Black, and Brown colour. I want to sorting out these collection in Pink, Black, Brown, Red and Blue colour format.

Can anyone give me an idea how could i do this?

Comment: Shopify has a walkthrough on adding a product sort dropdown, including some example Liquid code for doing this, available here: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/collections/add-sort-order-menu

Comment: Try handling it through product tags.

Answer (score 0):

It could have changed, but the last time I checked, if you sorted your products in a collection using Shopify Admin, that would not reflect on your website. So a company asked me to fix that. I made an App where you could sort the elements in a collection, for example, by colour, and then once that was done, the products would show up in that order on your website.

If it turns out you still cannot sort products in a collection, send me a message and maybe I can install that old App on your store for a small fee.